# Proving $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} ({1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {{( - 1 )^n}{{( {\frac{{\sin nx}}{{nx}}})}^2}} } )= \frac 12$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Could you show me $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}{{\left( {\frac{{\sin nx}}{{nx}}} \right)}^2}} } \right) = \frac{1}{2}.\tag{1}$$

These day, I want to write a article about the sums of divergent series. In Hardy's book [Divergent Series](https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries), he show me a method proposed by Riemann with
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}{{\left( {\frac{{\sin nx}}{{nx}}} \right)}^2}} } \right) ,$$ from which we can obtain $$1-1+1-1+\cdots=\frac12.$$
I hope someone tell me how to prove (1),Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We begin with the function $f(x)$ as represented by the series

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sin^2 nx}{n^2x^2} \tag 1$$

Using the identity

$$\sin^2nx=\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{2}$$

in $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1-\cos  2nx}{n^2x^2} \\\\
&=\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2x^2}-\frac12\text{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{e^{i2nx}}{n^2x^2}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{24x^2}-\frac{1}{2x^2}\text{Re}\left(\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{i2x}\right)\right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

We expand $\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{i2x}\right)$ in a series around $x=0$ to find

$$\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{i2x}\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}-i2\log (2)x+ x^2+O(x^3) \tag 3$$

Then, upon substituting $(3)$ into $(2)$ we have

$$f(x)=-\frac12 +O(x)$$

Finally, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sin^2 nx}{n^2x^2} \right)=\frac12}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**NOTE:**

If we inappropriately interchange the limit with the series and use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 nx}{n^2x^2}=1$, we obtain the absurd conclusion that

$$1-1+1-1+1\cdots =\frac12$$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by absurd conclusion, but it is not that far fetched since $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n = \lim_{x\rightarrow -1}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \lim_{x\rightarrow -1}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{2} \,.$$

Comment: How do you justify the first equality?  You've used illegitimate analysis to arrive at an erroneous result.

Comment: @diger Only in the sense of distribution does that analysis make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by distributional sense? As in $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin{nx}}{nx}$ is only defined for $\Im(x)=0$?

Comment: Oh and the function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is analytic for $x<1$ whose analytic continuation is finite with value $1/2$ at $x=-1$. So by comparison if the value of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ should take any value consistent with the formal series (the series of $f(x)$ converges for all $x>0$ and has an analytic continuation) then it must be the unique value obtained from analytic continuation.

Comment: @diger First, stand down!  Your first written equality is simply incorrect.  The sequence of partial sums of the series alternate between $1$ and $0$ and hence the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$ DIVERGES.  Inasmuch as the limit of the series $\lim_{\to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=1/2$ it is evidently not equal to the divergent series.  I suggest you research generalized functions since it's apparent you failed to understand my comment.

Comment: I do very well understand your argument, but the procedure of analytic continuation should be applicable here.

Comment: It cannot be applied to justify interchanging the limit with the summation.  If we appeal to the theory of distributions (aka generalized functions), then the series of alternating signs has as regularization the value $1/2$.  I doubt if the OP had any intention but to use classical real analysis and not distribution theory

Comment: If you still fixate on my first equality, forget about it. It is of course not correct in a rigorous sense, but it doesn't affect my argument about $f(x)$ has an analytic continuation whose formal power series at $x=0$ coincides with the formal power series of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ at $x=-1$. Hence the analytically continued values agree.

Comment: @diger You opened this by asking what I meant by an absurd conclusion.  It should be very clear from the short Note section as to the meaning.  One cannot simply interchange the original limit with the summation and expect to arrive at the correct result.  In fact, it is illegitimate here to interchange the order of operations.  Attempting to do so yields a divergent series.

Comment: You don't want to understand.... anyway good bye!

Comment: @diger I understand that you haven't listened to anything I've said.

Comment: I think the same vice versa. Good job!

Comment: You are being pedantic about dominated convergence, but that is precisely what I'm not talking about at all.

Comment: @Diger I am not talking about dominated convergence whatsoever.  Again, you are displaying your lack of understanding.

Comment: So you are not talking about changing the order of limit and summation?

Comment: @diger Both the DCT and a standard theorem on uniform convergence give sufficient conditions, not a necessary ones, to interchange orders of operation.  Those conditions aren't present here.  That does not imply automatically that interchanging operations is illegitimate.  But inasmuch as we arrive at a non-sensical result upon such an interchange, we know that the interchange is illegitimate.

Comment: Sure. I know these conditions aren't sattisfied. But I try to rephrase my approach 1 more time more generally: Let $f_1(x)$ be a convergent power series on the interval $(-1,1)$ and $f_2(x)$ another convergent power series on $(0,a)$. If $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ both admit an analytic continuation $\tilde{f}_1(x)$ and $\tilde{f}_2(x)$ respectively and if the formal power series $f_1(-1)$ and $f_2(0)$ agree, then $\tilde{f}_1(-1)=\tilde{f}_2(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking partial sums of the series and evaluating the limits, you get the following identity
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  (-1)^n{\left(\frac{\sin nx}{nx} \right)^2} = 1+\frac{-\pi^2-6 \text{Li}_2(-e^{-2 i x})-6 \text{Li}_2(-e^{2 i x})}{24 x^2}$$
Now let's take the limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \Bigg(1+\frac{-\pi^2-6 \text{Li}_2(-e^{-2 i x})-6 \text{Li}_2(-e^{2 i x})}{24 x^2}\Bigg)$$
$$ = 1+ \frac{1}{24}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\pi^2-6 \text{Li}_2(-e^{-2 i x})-6 \text{Li}_2(-e^{2 i x})}{x^2}$$
$$ = 1+ \frac{1}{48}\lim_{x \to 0}\left[-\frac{24e^{-2ix}}{1+e^{-2ix}}-\frac{24e^{2ix}}{1+e^{2ix}}\right]$$
$$ = 1+ \frac{1}{48}\left[-\frac{24}{2}-\frac{24}{2}\right]$$
$$ = 1- \frac{24}{48} = 1-\frac{1}{2} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$$